# Getting trouble in the jsPdf auto-table Custom width Columns

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

Hi all Am trying to Increase my Specified column size Column size , So i used  like this `{columnStyles: {xxx: {columnWidth: 18}}}` , Column size was increased but next lines's are getting affected . That mean's next line is `theme: 'grid',` mean's it's not working . Can someone clarify me pls . Here is My code ,

```js
  doc.autoTable(getColumns(), getData(), //{columnStyles: {steps: {columnWidth: 65}}},
            {
             theme: 'grid', // 'striped', 'grid' or 'plain'
             headerStyles: {
                    fillColor: [189, 200, 255],
                    textColor: [12, 1, 1]
                },
               // margin: { top: 50, left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 0 },
             styles: {
                   overflow: 'linebreak',
                   columnWidth: 110,
                   lineWidth: 2,
                   lineColor: [85, 51, 27]
                   
                 },
                 pageBreak: 'avoid',
                 beforePageContent: function(data) {
                  doc.setFontSize(10);
                     doc.text("Process Name :"+mainData.name+"  ||   "+"Description :"+mainData.description, 20, 15);
                     
                 },
                 //startY: doc.autoTableEndPosY() + 20,
                columnStyles: {
                  //0: {columnWidth: 200}
                }
              });
                      //doc.save("xxx.pdf");
```

[image]

Comment: The code posted contains syntax errors and is not correctly indented. Fix this and I'll take a look at it again. That said it looks like your issue is due to none matching brackets. You are sending in four parameters to doc.autoTable() while it only supports three (two option objects)

Comment: Syntax error cleared..

Comment: Sweet! Hmm, do you which to increase the width of a single cell, and not of the column?

Comment: I have 5 columns , But some Columns occupies more space some occupies less space ex: index number  , So i need to increase or decrease them .

Comment: Waiting For your Answer :)

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand the issue. What do you mean by this `Column size was increased but next lines's are getting affected`? It sounds like you succeeded in increasing the size of the column, but were surprised to see all rows affected?

Comment: That means, Column size increased but in that next line i gave "THEME" as "GRID " But i doesn't work. Table data's are there without Lines ie) Look like plain table

Comment: No error ! But something weird it is .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/119015/discussion-between-simon-bengtsson-and-becky).

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the pdfsize , below are the formats

```
  pageFormats = { // Size in pt of various paper formats
        'a0': [2383.94, 3370.39], 'a1': [1683.78, 2383.94],
        'a2': [1190.55, 1683.78], 'a3': [841.89, 1190.55],
        'a4': [595.28, 841.89], 'a5': [419.53, 595.28],
        'a6': [297.64, 419.53], 'a7': [209.76, 297.64],
        'a8': [147.40, 209.76], 'a9': [104.88, 147.40],
        'a10': [73.70, 104.88], 'b0': [2834.65, 4008.19],
        'b1': [2004.09, 2834.65], 'b2': [1417.32, 2004.09],
        'b3': [1000.63, 1417.32], 'b4': [708.66, 1000.63],
        'b5': [498.90, 708.66], 'b6': [354.33, 498.90],
        'b7': [249.45, 354.33], 'b8': [175.75, 249.45],
        'b9': [124.72, 175.75], 'b10': [87.87, 124.72],
        'c0': [2599.37, 3676.54], 'c1': [1836.85, 2599.37],
        'c2': [1298.27, 1836.85], 'c3': [918.43, 1298.27],
        'c4': [649.13, 918.43], 'c5': [459.21, 649.13],
        'c6': [323.15, 459.21], 'c7': [229.61, 323.15],
        'c8': [161.57, 229.61], 'c9': [113.39, 161.57],
        'c10': [79.37, 113.39], 'dl': [311.81, 623.62],
        'letter': [612, 792],
        'government-letter': [576, 756],
        'legal': [612, 1008],
        'junior-legal': [576, 360],
        'ledger': [1224, 792],
        'tabloid': [792, 1224],
        'credit-card': [153, 243]
    };
```

You have to say as `var pdfsize = 'a1';`