# Uncaught TypeError in jsPdf autotable

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

Am trying to print the dynamic data's into pdf file using jsPdf Auto-table . When am doing this i got some kind of error's like

```
The headers should be an object or array, is: function     (jspdf.plugin.autotable.js:10 )
The data should be an object or array, is: function        (jspdf.plugin.autotable.js:10)
TypeError: t.forEach is not a function     (angular.js:12314)
```

Here is my code -

```
var getColumns = function () {
    return [
        { title: "ID", dataKey: "id" },
        { title: "Name", dataKey: "first_name" },
        { title: "Email", dataKey: "email" },
        { title: "City", dataKey: "city" },
        { title: "Country", dataKey: "country" },
        { title: "Expenses", dataKey: "expenses" }
    ];
};

function getData(mainSteps) {
    mainSteps = mainSteps || 4;
    //var sentence = faker.lorem.words(12);
    var data = [];
    for (var j = 1; j <= rowCount; j++) {
        data.push({
            id: j,
            first_name: this.getSteps(),
            email: this.getSteps(),
            country: this.getSteps(),
            city: this.getSteps()(),
            expenses: this.getSteps()
            // text: shuffleSentence(sentence),
            //text2: shuffleSentence(sentence)
        });
    }
    return data;
}

var pdfsize = 'a4';
var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', pdfsize);

doc.autoTable(getColumns, getData, {
    theme: 'grid', // 'striped', 'grid' or 'plain'
    headerStyles: {
        fillColor: [12, 234, 227],
        textColor: [12, 1, 1]
    },
    // margin: { top: 50, left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 0 },
    styles: {
        overflow: 'linebreak',
        columnWidth: 88
    },
    beforePageContent: function (data) {

        doc.text("Process Name :" + mainData.name + "  ||   " + "Description :" + mainData.description, 40, 30);

    },
    //startY: doc.autoTableEndPosY() + 20,
    columnStyles: {
        0: { columnWidth: 200 }
    }
});

//startY: doc.autoTableEndPosY() + 20
doc.save(mainData.name + ".pdf");
```

Note : If the error is in my code mean's i can find the solution for that, But it says *error is in (jspdf.plugin.autotable.js:10 )* and *(angular.js:12314)* so am getting confused here. Can someone clarify me please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the errors explain the input data must be arrays or objects. In your case that simply means calling the functions instead of sending them to autotable. Replace this

`doc.autoTable(getColumns, getData, {...});`

with

`doc.autoTable(getColumns(), getData(), {...});`

Comment: Yes, you are correct . That was my " Careless" mistake :(

Comment: ,Hey hi.. i have one small doubt . I'm trying to apply custom width column . So i followed your instruction in your github site. But after applying that it seems like i didn't work for me . Can you help me pls . Here is my code --> {title: "Category", dataKey: "cate",width: 20}   ,

Comment: or is there any other way's to do that ?

Comment: Where did you see the mentioning of the width option? The github page should point to the `columnWidth` style which is used something like this: `doc.autoTable(columns, rows, {columnStyles: {cate: {columnWidth: 20}}})`

Comment: I tried in this way also --> columnStyles: {cate: {columnWidth: 200}}But it say's ---->  (jspdf.plugin.autotable.js:10 )Use of deprecated option: column.width, use column.styles.columnWidth instead

Comment: That is just a warning that gets outputted if `column.width` is defined and should disappear if you remove that option and only use `columnWidth`. If you are having issues despite using `columnWidth` it is probably easier if you submit a new question with more complete code. `columnWidth` should work as there is an example using it in the repo.

Comment: Waiting for your Answer buddy --->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38540921/getting-trouble-in-the-jspdf-auto-table-custom-width-columns